# Redis репликация

Tags: redis

Имеется 4 сервера, на всех установлен `Redis` и настроена реплика. 1-ый сервер мастер  остальные слейвы. При падении 1-го сервера, работа переходит на 2-ой. Возможно ли настроить `Redis` таким образом чтобы мастером становился следующий по приоритету активный сервер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После прочтения многих статей и докладов, выявил что репликация мастер-мастер на данный момент невозможна. Выход из ситуации на данный момент вижу только использование Redis-Sentinel, который мониторит падение мастера и в случае чего назначает одного из слейва новым мастером

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации в кластере редис может быть одновременно [несколько мастеров](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).
Например: 
`redis-cli --cluster add-node 127.0.0.1:7006 127.0.0.1:7000 --cluster-slave` -- Добавление в кластер сервера реплики.
`redis-cli --cluster add-node 127.0.0.1:7006 127.0.0.1:7000` -- Добавление ещё одного мастера.